# Generate transparent JPEG with alphamap RAM usage issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, bitmapdata

I generate a transparent bitmap in flash with two jpegs. One is black and white for reading the BitmapDataChannel and the other picture is the actual image.

this is my code:

```
private var sourceBitmap:BitmapData;
private var alphaBitmap:BitmapData;
private var outputBitmap:BitmapData;
private var bitmap:Bitmap;

//Updated Code:
private var sourceByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray(), outputByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray(), alphaByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
private var jpegencoderoptions = new JPEGEncoderOptions(0);

//get image from library
this.sourceBitmap = new imageFromLibrary();
//Updated: encode sourceBitmap
this.sourceBitmap.encode(this.sourceBitmap.rect, jpegencoderoptions, this.sourceByteArray);
//create new bitmapData with dimensions of sourcimage.      
this.outputBitmap = new BitmapData(this.sourceBitmap.width, this.sourceBitmap.height, true, 0x00000000);
//Updated: encode outputBitmap
this.outputBitmap.encode(this.outputBitmap.rect, jpegencoderoptions, this.outputByteArray);

this.outputBitmap.lock();

//copy the pixels from source to output
this.outputBitmap.copyPixels(this.sourceBitmap, this.sourceBitmap.rect, new Point());
//free memory and dispose source
this.sourceBitmap.dispose();
//Updated: clear sourceByteArray
this.sourceByteArray.clear();

//get alphamap from library         
this.alphaBitmap = new alphamapFromLibrary();
//Updated: encode alphaBitmap 
this.alphaBitmap.encode(this.alphaBitmap.rect, jpegencoderoptions, this.alphaByteArray);

//copy the channel from alpha to output
this.outputBitmap.copyChannel(this.alphaBitmap, this.alphaBitmap.rect, new Point(), BitmapDataChannel.RED, BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA);

//free memory and dispose alpha
this.alphaBitmap.dispose();
//Updated: clear alphaByteArray
this.alphaByteArray.clear();

this.bitmap = new Bitmap(this.outputBitmap);
```

The code works great and it generates a transparent image for me. But my problem now is the heavy RAM load. On older smartphones it exceeds the RAM and the game is closing itself.

The mainproblem is with this:
I load the sourceBitmap and this takes RAM, and after this I generate the new BitmapData "outputBitmap". With this I have 2 times a BitmapData in RAM with the same dimensions.

My question is now: can I skip some steps and load my sourceBitmap, set transparent to true and copy the channels to this source instead of loading source, create output and so on?

**EDIT:**

I updated my code now with `BitmapData.encode()` to encode my BitmapDatas to JPEG. But there is not  always a change in memory usage. Sometimes the memory usage is increased after encode, sometimes it's less and sometimes it's no change.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image?  And I assume PNG encoding is out of the question?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are trying to create but I think I have an idea. Something slower you could try is to loop through the pixels and directly write them out to the new bitmap if they pass the alpha test. Unless these images are huge I don't 3 images would give you a memory issue. There is a good chance your memory is being hogged somewhere else and these functions are just pushing it over the limit. You also try to lower the PPI on the images.

Comment: my background image is about 5000 x 1600 in size (~32MB RAM x 2 = ~64MB). And I tested it allready to loop trough all pixels with getPixel and setPixel. But it takes tooooo long.
@Michael Brewer-Davis what can I do with PNG encoding?

Comment: If `imageFromLibrary` were a PNG, it could include the alpha channel and you would not need to merge two images.

Comment: Yeah, but when I use PNG the game starts to lag, when I use 2 JPEGs the game don't lag, but the memory will be exhausted sometimes. Another problem: when my FLA file is too big, I can't publish it anymore. and 1 PNG is much more filesize than 2 JPEGs. I use the pictures as backgrounds. Sometimes it works with starting the game and playing. But sometimes the RAM is exhausted when the user has other programs running in the background.

Comment: Isn't there a way to dispose the bitmapdata after bitmap is created to free memory but hold the image on stage?

Comment: It sounds a bit strange that you get a performance difference between PNGs and JPEGs since what you have in memory in the end is always a raw BitmapData. The only issue I see is that PNG's are much bigger so it might take longer to load them. I recommend you to try Joa Ebert's Reducer which allows you to save transparent PNGs in the way that the Flash IDE does it internally - using a JPEG for RGB and a PNG for the alpha channel: http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2009/08/08/reducer/ - of course this will require some changes to the way you handle your resource library.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds strange with the performance difference, but it's true and that's what I don't understand. But the reducer doesn't help me at all, cause I don't have an issue with the filesize of the swf.

Comment: I too think its strange that you have performance issues with a PNG instead of a JPEG... I would double check that. Also, one possible solution would be to split your original bitmaps into several smaller ones, and compose the big one in smaller steps, so you would never have two 5000x1600 bitmaps simultaneously in memory, but only one 5000x1600, and let's say one 1000x800 (so you get 10 steps). The extra mile would be to never really use such a big bitmap, but to only have in memory what you need in different stages of the game (depending on you game needs).

Comment: Also, I would deeply revise any app that needs to use even one 5000x1600 bitmap on a mobile device ;)

Comment: Hmm, it seems that PNGs require very little extra CPU energy to display than JPGs and the JPG decoder is much faster than the PNG decoder. This is why I have the performance issues.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no such thing as a transparent JPG. Transparent bitmap, GIF, or PNG, yes. JPG? No.

Comment: I know. But the compression of my images are JPEG and I create a transparent bitmap out of them.

Comment: 1. Sorry, but I can't do that. 2.The images themself have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify: the decoding process of a JPG vs a PNG is indeed different and could cause a performance issue, but only in the moment of decoding, which is when you first retrieve the image from the library and create the bitmap (just this line: this.sourceBitmap = new imageFromLibrary();). After the decoding process though, performance should be exactly the same between both bitmaps, as long as both are 32bit (transparent, which is your case).

Comment: Also, please explain why did you added the JPEGEncode process in your code, as it doesn't really do anything... at least from the code you posted.

Comment: And to your previous question: "Isn't there a way to dispose the bitmapdata after bitmap is created to free memory but hold the image on stage?" > No, an image on the stage will always be represented by a BitmapData, and it will always use up the same memory. The only way to save some RAM would be to not use a transparent BitmapData, but use some kind of workaround, like blendmodes or mascs, to simulate transparency, but this depends directly on the image and the surrounding graphics, and could eventually impact performance, or even memory consumption on the internal rendering phase.

Comment: I tried the JPEGEncoding only and is not insinde my actual code anymore. But to follow my steps and what I have done so far I didn't edited my post. About the JPG vs PNG issue: this is strange, cause I tested it with PNGs again and it start's to lag again and after this I tested with JPG again and it doen't lag. THIS is what I don't understand and THIS is my problem why I can't use PNGs and must create transparent Bitmap out of JPG.